# elasticsearch / nest : ideas for doing equivalent of sql joins between multi types?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I know that it is said  in [elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html) that it is not adviced to do some sort of stuffs but i want to do equivalent of sql joins between different types.

I am using nest the c# library that allow me to do some dynamically built request and to    successive requests that can use  the result of previous requests.

I see  a solution for simulatting sub-queries:
Make a first request in first types that get in answere a list of id that are uses as a  join column

Make a second request in a second type  with the list of id that i have  obtained sooner in a filter query. That allow me to make the sql "in"  equivalent

Maybe a better solution appear to you .

I wrote quickly an example:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"person"}}
{"name":"Michael", "birthdate":"1989-10-1", "sport":"Baseball", "id_person" : 1}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"person"}}
{"name":"Bob", "birthdate":"1989-11-2", "sport":"Basketball","id_person" : 2}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"person"}}
{"name":"Jim", "birthdate":"1988-10-3", "sport":"Basketball", "id_person" : 3}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"person"}}
{"name":"Steve", "birthdate":"1987-10-3", "sport":"Basketball", "id_person" : 4}

POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "expenses", "id_person" : 1, "date_bill" : "2012-10-1"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "income", "id_person" : 1, "date_bill" : "2014-10-8"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "expenses", "id_person" : 1, "date_bill" : "2010-04-9"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "income", "id_person" : 2, "date_bill" : "2015-12-5"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "expenses", "id_person" : 2, "date_bill" : "2015-12-5"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "incomes", "id_person" : 2, "date_bill" : "2015-12-5"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "income", "id_person" : 2, "date_bill" : "2015-12-10"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "expenses", "id_person" : 3, "date_bill" : "2016-06-5"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"bill"}}
{"type_bill" : "income", "id_person" : 4, "date_bill" : "2015-08-8"}

POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"interview"}}
{"date_match" : "2016-01-1", "id_person" : 1, "topic" : "sport", "communication_way" : "radio"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"interview"}}
{"date_match" : "2016-02-1", "id_person" : 1, "topic" : "sport","communication_way" : "radio"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"interview"}}
{"date_match" : "2016-06-1", "id_person" : 2, "topic" : "women","communication_way" : "tv"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"interview"}}
{"date_match" : "2016-10-1", "id_person" : 3, "topic" : "myself", "communication_way" : "tv"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"interview"}}
{"date_match" : "2016-01-5", "id_person" : 3, "topic" : "sport", "communication_way" : "press"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"interview"}}
{"date_match" : "2016-01-1", "id_person" : 4, "topic" : "women" , "communication_way" : "press"}


GET test_index/person/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : { "sport" : "Basketball" }
    }, 
    "_source": "id_person"
}
```

with nest i could build some bound request from result of a first:

```
GET test_index/person/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : { "sport" : "Basketball" }
    }, 
    "_source": "id_person"
}
```

I use result of first request (ids 2 3 and 4) in the filter query of my first request

```
POST /test_index/bill/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type_bill": "income"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id_person": 2
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "id_person": 3
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "id_person": 4
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have others idea that would use other mechanisms or elasticsearch queries?

Comment: Did you consider using [parent-child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html)?

Comment: thank you @rob, does it suppose to normalize all types in  hierarchical types?

Comment: Based on your example `person` will be parent for `bill` and `interview` types. That way you can do one request to ES saying "Hey, give me bill documents where parent id is x". Does it make sense to you?